# Explain the relationship of ESB technology with EAI and SOA?

Tags: soa, esb, eai

Can anyone explain the relationship of ESB technology with EAI and SOA? and give me some examples.

Answer (score 1):

EAI is an integration framework composed of a group of technologies and services which form a middleware/ESB to enable integration of systems and applications within an enterprise, and/or across enterprises.

ESB is software architecture model used for implementing communication between software applications in a service-oriented architecture (SOA).

Examples:

Oracle Services Bus (OSB)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/service-bus/overview/index.html

IBM WebSphere Enterprise Service Bus:

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/wsesb

SOA is an architectural pattern in which application components provide services to other components/clients via communication protocol (SOAP, REST).

SOA architecture is independent of any vendor, product or technology.